# How to break js function when the arguments equal a specific value in Firefox debugger?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I want to debug a website that is built from millions of lines of js code, and I want to find the function that will receive a specific value as one of the arguments. Is it possible to break the execution when any function receive a specific value as one of the arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional breakpoint in

- [Chrome's debugger](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/breakpoints/#conditional-loc)
- [Firefox' debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_conditional_breakpoint)

Alternatively, if the browser of your choice does not have similar functionality, you could invoke the `debugger` statement conditionally (if you can modify the code):

```
 if(value === "wanted") debugger;
```

however that only works if you know the functions that might receive a specific parameter

> Is it possible to break the execution when any function receive a specific value as one of the arguments?

No, that's close to impossible. Adding a breakpoint to "any function" will probably slow down execution a lot, if it's even possible. Doing so programmatically might work somehow, though it seems like a lot of work for little benefit. If you know the value, you probably also know the source and can debug from there.

Comment: In fact, the source (location) of the code is what I want to find.

Comment: But then you could just place a breakpoint at a place where the value occurs and go up the callstack?

Comment: I don't know where the value occurs.